# How do I find the payload of a Sendgrid email sent by ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, sendgrid, payload

I'm working with SendGrid support to determine why categories stopped working on my multipart email campaigns (the text-only one is fine). If I intentionally set the content-type of an HTML email as "text/plain" the email displays the header data, text and raw html all on a single email, but will get its category. Otherwise the email looks correct, but there's no category.

SendGrid has asked me to send them a copy of the payload and I'm not sure what that is or how to find it. They said "If you are familiar with running a telnet test then that is what we are looking for." I'm not familiar with telnet tests. This is the info from the screenshot they provided as an example of what they're looking for:

```
220 Hi! This is Rob's hMailServer!
ehlo panoply-tech.com
250-SAGE013963
250-SIZE 20480000
250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
AUTH LOGIN
334 VXN1ea5bbVUG
YT3TQBHbhM9WBHKTDGUjeD65WQ20=
235 authenticated.
MAIL FROM: mayes@panoply-tech.com
250 OK
RCPT TO: cstickings@demosagecrm.com
250 OK
DATA
354 OK, send.
Subject: This is a test email
Hi Clemence,
Just sending you a test email.
.
250 Queued <25.927 seconds>
```

I went to .rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.8/lib/action_mailer/base.rb and found a method called "set_payload_for_mail" but what that produces does seem to be like their example:

```
{"mailer":"B2c::B2cSendGridMailer",
"message_id":"5d0b979767c26_16f2c3fc04043f9c84968e@Domain-Person.local.mail",
"subject":"TEST: 26_txt","to":["person@domain.com"],
"from":["info@another.com"],"date":"2019-06-20T09:26:31.000-05:00",
"mail":"Date: Thu, 20 Jun 2019 09:26:31 -0500\r\nFrom: info@another.com\r\nTo: person@domain.com\r\nMessage-ID: \u003c5d0b979767c26_16f2c3fc04043f9c84968e@Domain-Person.local.mail\u003e\r\nSubject: TEST: 26_txt\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n
X-SMTPAPI: {\"category\":[\"html_false\"]}\r\n
X-SMTPAPI: {\"filters\": {\"ganalytics\": {\"settings\": {\"enable\":1}}}}
\r\n\r\nHi there, but text\r\n"}
```

I know in the Google inbox, you can click "Show Original" for an email and see the header info, etc. I've sent that to them but that didn't have what they needed.

```
  def b2c_tester(html=false, content)
        e_domain = 'careinhomes.com'
        @mailer_path = "app/views/b2c/b2c_send_grid_mailer"
        @from = "info@careinhomes.com"
        @recipients = ['gina@pipelinesuccess.com']
        @subject = html ? "#{DateTime.now.minute.to_s}_html" : 
              "#{DateTime.now.minute.to_s}_txt"

        header_category = {"category": ["html_#{html}"]}
        headers['X-SMTPAPI'] = header_category.to_json

        if html
          msg = tester_mail_with_opts({domain: e_domain}, content)
        else
          msg = tester_mail_plain_text_with_opts(
              "b2c_tester",{domain: e_domain})
        end
        msg
    end

   #content ex: 'text/plain', 'text/html', 'multipart/alternative', etc
    def tester_mail_with_opts(delivery_options={}, content=nil)
      mail_opts = set_mail_opts(delivery_options)
      unless content.nil?
        mail_opts[:content_type] = content
      end
      mail mail_opts
    end

  def set_mail_opts(delivery_options={})
      @subject = "TEST: #{@subject}" unless Rails.env.production?
      # Required
      mail_opts = {
          to: @recipients,
          from: @from,
          subject: @subject,
      }

      mail_opts[:template_path] = @template_path if @template_path
      mail_opts[:content_type] = @content_type if @content_type

      # Do delivery options
      mail_opts[:delivery_method_options] = DELIVERY_OPTIONS
      mail_opts[:delivery_method_options] = 
        mail_opts[:delivery_method_options].merge(delivery_options) 
              unless delivery_options.blank?
      mail_opts
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In ActionMailer's base model is a method called deliver_mail that extracts the payload and you can capture it that way. It appears that, for my problem, the payload is an empty hash.

This is what a healthy payload should look like from ActionMailer:

```
{"mailer":"B2c::B2cSendGridMailer","message_id":"5d10dacb26dc2_17fb93ff52483b9c8952bf@Domain-Person.local.mail","subject":"TEST: 14_txt","to":["person@domain.com"],"from":["info@another.com"],"date":"2019-06-24T09:14:35.000-05:00","mail":"Date: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 09:14:35 -0500\r\nFrom: info@another.com\r\nTo: person@domain.com\r\nMessage-ID: \u003c5d10dacb26dc2_17fb93ff52483b9c8952bf@Domain-Person.local.mail\u003e\r\nSubject: TEST: 14_txt\r\nMime-Version: 1.0\r\nContent-Type: text/plain;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\nX-SMTPAPI: {\"category\":[\"html_false\"]}\r\nX-SMTPAPI: {\"filters\": {\"ganalytics\": {\"settings\": {\"enable\":1}}}}\r\n\r\nHi there, but text\r\n"}
```